# What does symbol / do at end of sql scripts?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, sqlplus

I have a sql script as follows. What does the symbol '/' at the end of this script do?

```
@create_file.sql;
@check_status.sql;
@update_status.sql;

/
show errors;
```

Comment: I know nothing about Oracle but my guess is that it's the equivalent of MSSQLs GO statement which executes the preceding t-sql as a batch then anything until the next GO or end of script as the next batch...am I close?

Comment: I'd add on Gergo's answer below.  / slash also re-execute the previous command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12004.htm):

> Executes the most recently executed SQL command or PL/SQL block which is stored in the SQL buffer.
>
> The buffer has no command history and does not record SQL*Plus commands.